# WPF: Color text in ListBox of TextBox based on property value

Tags: c#, wpf

Relatively new to WPF.

I have the following XAML / Code which will display the ItemNames (a property of a class) in an ObservableCollection of said class.  What I want to do is to color the text a different color IF the IsAvailable value is false, and leave it black if it is true.  How do I setup a check and modify the color?

Data Class:

```
    public class PIProductionData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string itemName;
    private bool isAvailable;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string ItemName
    {
        get => this.itemName;
        set
        {
            this.itemName = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemName"));
        }
    }

    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get => this.isAvailable;
        set
        {
            this.isAvailable = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsAvailable"));
        }
    }
}
```

Collection Class:

```
 public class PIProducts : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public const int RawIndex = 0;
    public const int Tier1Index = 1;
    public const int Tier2Index = 2;
    public const int Tier3Index = 3;
    public const int Tier4Index = 4;

    private List<ObservableCollection<PIProductionData>> items;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<PIProductionData> Raw
    {
        get => this.items[0];
        set
        {
            this.items[0] = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Raw"));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PIProductionData> Tier1
    {
        get => this.items[1];
        set
        {
            this.items[1] = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Tier1"));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductionLists.Raw} Style="{StaticResource MyListBoxStyle}"/>

<Style x:Key="MyListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ItemName, Mode=OneWay}"  Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextBox Style may contain a DataTrigger:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Besides that, the TextBox should probably be a TextBlock, because you don't want to edit the text.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
...
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```